# Answering your own question? Accept it. 

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer, notifications, self-answer

I was [reviewing](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-answers) the users' first answers, 
and I see a *lot* of people
who has answered his own question,  **but** hasn't accepted it, because of:

- He's new on the site and doesn't know that answers can (should!) be accepted.
- He's new on the site and thinks accepting a self-answer is a *bad thing*.
- He had to wait to accept his answer and forgot about that.
- He intentionally leave it unaccepted (very few cases).

And I have to make tons of comments asking those people to do so.

### The proposal

Wouldn't it be great to **let the site ask you to accept your answer**?
I know there's a waiting period: if it hasn't expired yet,
remember the user to accept his answer when it expires.

For example, by showing a notification or sending him an email when
the waiting period expires.

Comment: In how many of those cases was the non-self-accept intentional?

Comment: User might forget to self-accept their answers since there's a waiting period. I'm not completely sure what the intentions behind that waiting periods are, but I'm certain your checkbox would undermine them.

Comment: You missed my point. I'm sure that some users just forget to accept their own answers or don't know how the system works, as you say. However, you -- and more importantly, the system -- have no idea whether it's intentional in any particular case. Sometimes, users may want to answer their own questions just to supplement existing answers. They may also want to leave other users' answers accepted to give reputation "thank-yous." (Also, most people don't appreciate being called "it.")

Comment: @PopularDemand Then, the user would ignore the notification / uncheck the option.

Comment: But that sounds like work. First, it's a bunch of upfront work for the devs to implement this system in the first place. There'll also be a lot of work for the users -- in much smaller chunks -- to notice that the answer form has an unusual layout once in a while. Unless you can prove that this change will be actively beneficial, it's not worth giving the team more stuff to do, adding complexity and breaking people's mental representations of how to use the site.

Comment: @PopularDemand oooops! I just noticed the "it". Sorry, english is not my matern language. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As you know, you can already accept your own answer. The delay is built in to allow others to provide answers that may be better than your own.

You are already prompted to accept an answer (or raise a bounty) if you revisit the question page and (I think) on your profile page.

There *may* be mileage in getting the system to remind low rep or new users, but that goes against the ethos of the sites.

Comment: @jmendeth - Your proposal isn't the solution to that problem though for the reason I've given in this answer.

Comment: @jmendeth - possibly, though a) that's a different question and b) I've a feeling it's already been asked.

Comment: @jmendeth - not the way you have it with a check box saying "accept this answer".

Comment: Okay, I didn't express myself well. Removing the checkbox.

Comment: Wow. Are you gonna get the reversal badge again? :)